# Building jcarsdsim with maven on IntelliJ Idea 15.04

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, simulator

So assume that I'm bulding [that](https://github.com/licel/jcardsim) repository from source. [Here](https://jcardsim.org/docs/getting-source-compiling) is the instructions given by the developer.

Аfter cloning it with built-in ItlliJ VCS tools I've modified default [`pom.xml`](http://pastebin.com/SHdHgusw) a bit in order maven to work.

So, after executing `mvn initialize` in maven console I got following log:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java" "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" -Didea.launcher.port=7537 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=15.0.4 initialize
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Java Card Runime Environment Simulator 3.0.4
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file (default) @ jcardsim ---
[INFO] pom.xml not found in api.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\java_card_kit-2_2_2\lib\api.jar to C:\Users\Foo\.m2\repository\oracle\javacard\api_classic\2.2.2\api_classic-2.2.2.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.527s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Mar 06 10:19:39 MSK 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/116M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is ok, I guess.

But when it comes to execute `mvn clean install` in order to make the `.jar` file I've got the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java" "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" -Didea.launcher.port=7538 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=15.0.4 clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Java Card Runime Environment Simulator 3.0.4
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ jcardsim ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Foo\Documents\GitHub\jcardsim\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file (default) @ jcardsim ---
[INFO] pom.xml not found in api.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\java_card_kit-2_2_2\lib\api.jar to C:\Users\Foo\.m2\repository\oracle\javacard\api_classic\2.2.2\api_classic-2.2.2.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ jcardsim ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Foo\Documents\GitHub\jcardsim\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ jcardsim ---
[INFO] Compiling 86 source files to C:\Users\Foo\Documents\GitHub\jcardsim\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:unpack (default) @ jcardsim ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: oracle.javacard:api_classic:2.2.2:jar
[INFO] Unpacking C:\Users\Foo\.m2\repository\oracle\javacard\api_classic\2.2.2\api_classic-2.2.2.jar to C:\Users\Foo\Documents\GitHub\jcardsim\target\classes with includes "**/*.class" and excludes ""
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default) @ jcardsim ---
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassReader.accept() should be called with EXPAND_FRAMES flag
    at org.objectweb.asm.commons.LocalVariablesSorter.visitFrame(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.commons.RemappingMethodAdapter.visitFrame(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.FrameNode.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.InsnList.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.licel.jcardsim.utils.JavaCardApiProcessor.proxyClass(JavaCardApiProcessor.java:92)
    at com.licel.jcardsim.utils.JavaCardApiProcessor.main(JavaCardApiProcessor.java:47)
    ... 6 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.245s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Mar 06 10:21:25 MSK 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/201M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default) on project jcardsim: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: ClassReader.accept() should be called with EXPAND_FRAMES flag -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Since I am new to the Java world and, especially, the Maven, I wonder what the problem is and how to properly fix it?

I'm running Windows 8.1 with `IntelliJ Idea 15.04`, `Java 1.8` and `JCSDK 2.2.2`

**Update**

[Here](https://diffchecker.com/frgtg6xn) is the diff between original and my `pom.xml`

[Here](http://pastebin.com/eQGbGnRi) is the output of `mvn -X clean install`

Comment: I did not check out the project but you can try the more verbose maven output using the -Xe flag.

Comment: Did you change any of the dependency versions in `pom.xml`, e.g. `org.ow2.asm/asm-all`? What changes you did in the `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you revert your change from

```
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
```

back to

```
<java.version>1.5</java.version>
```

it will work.

If you want to generate Java 8 bytecode you need to amend the class `JavaCardApiProcessor.java` in an appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

I have included several pull requests and this version is using a more recent code base in [my fork](https://github.com/koh-osug/jcardsim). There is also a new released [Maven package](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.ohmesoftware/jcardsim).